# ValueError: Cannot override primary key field

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, mongoengine

I have a base document class `Feed` from which `RSS` and `Channels` inherit. Here is the definition:

```py
class Feed(Document):
    meta_info = EmbeddedDocument(MetaInfo, default=MetaInfo, required=True)
    name = StringField()
    link = StringField()

    meta = {'allow_inheritance': True}
```

I want my two other classes, `RSS` and `Channels`, to be able to inherit the `Feed` document with its embedded document `MetaInfo`. However, when the whole file is run, alongside the following code:

```py
class Channel(Feed):
    channel_id = IntField(primary_key=True, unique=True, required=True)
    update_interval = IntField(default=300, required=True)

# similar class for RSS but with different fields
```

I get the following error:

```py
  File "/Users/komron/dev/github/courant/src/models/channels.py", line 9, in <module>
    class Channel(Feed):
  File "/Users/komron/.local/share/virtualenvs/courant-Dv7-v42z/lib/python3.7/sitepackages/mongoengine/base/metaclasses.py", line 407, in __new__
    raise ValueError("Cannot override primary key field")
ValueError: Cannot override primary key field
```

What am I doing wrong? Are there any restrictions placed on inheritance with MongoEngine that I should be aware of? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you use inheritance, both `Feed`, `RSS` and `Channels` classes' documents will live in the same collection (named `feed` by default). The problem is that you can't have multiple primary keys within 1 collection, your subclasses need to share the same field that is defined as primary key and it should be defined in the parent `Feed` class.

Note that when you don't specify anything (like in your `Feed` class), MongoEngine implicitly uses `id=ObjectIdField(primary_key=True, default=bson.ObjectId)` behind the scenes. This explains why you get an error related to overriding it.

This [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59511594/6203472) related to primary key might also be of interest

Comment: I'd like to keep the two objects in different feeds though. Is that possible?

Comment: If you want to keep the RSS and Channels in separate collections, then you can use the abstract classes concept (http://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/defining-documents.html#abstract-classes).